# how to access Node JS "homepage" or PUBLIC_URL value in CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I want to host my React App on IIS under a subfolder of my website. I have setup `homepage` in `package.json`

```
{
    "homepage": "/MyApp"
}
```

my app working fine, however, I have one issue from my SCSS: my `public/fonts` folder and `public/images` folder are getting from website root folder, not in MyApp sub-folder

#### from website root

`http://myhost.com/fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf`
`http://myhost.com/images/myIcon.png`

#### not my expected

`http://myhost.com/MyApp/fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf`
`http://myhost.com/MyApp/images/myIcon.png`

---

I am using `create-react-app`, the top component `App.jsx` import `App.scss`
```js
import './App.scss';
```

in `App.scss`, import `variables.scss` like this:

```css
@import "./themes/generated/variables.base.scss";
.my-icon-class {
    background: url('/images/myIcon.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
......
```

in `variables.scss`, I have a font variable which src point to `fonts` folder located in `public\fonts`
and CSS class background: URL()

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MavenPro-Regular';
  src: url('/fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Is there a `PUBLIC_URL` variable I can use in SCSS?

A colleague told me to move fonts and images folder into `src` folder, then change all URL from `URL('/fonts/...')` to `URL('fonts/...')` but I think it may be not a good structure (or I am wrong?). I hope to find out what's wrong in my setting.

Comment: @anderssonola this doesn't answer his question and there are reasons why you would want images to come through the public folder like when you have thousands of dynamic image paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous understanding of Public folder's usage is wrong, I should put fonts and images into `src` folder, let them bundled into `static` folder, instead of letting them direct copy into the build folder:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

For CSS file, fonts and image should reference to an absolute path, so I should not reference the source to the public folder:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/829

That's the reason why I should move my fonts and images files into `src` folder for bundling.

Comment: Normally you do want to put images, fonts, etc in the src folder. But there are reasons why the public folder can be used like when you have thousands of dynamic image paths coming in from a config file